# Python flask TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, json, flask

I get the following error :

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What I want to do is a simple `json` data from a `url` and show it on a webpage by Python Flask.

the following code is :

```
@app.route('/data', methods=['GET'])
def data():
    params = {
    'api_key': '{API_KEY}',
    }
    url='https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/yy/yy/'
    r= requests.get(url, params=params, verify=False).content
    return render_template('data.html', time=json.loads(r)['time'])


html:

{% block body %}
<h1>data</h1>
 {% for ON in time %}
   <div>{{ON["time"]}}</div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made `time=json.loads(r)['time']`.  and then again iterating through the `time` variable in the template. Error clearly states that `time` here is an integer and cant be iterated. So, take a look at the following line

```
return render_template('data.html', time=json.loads(r)['time'])
```

try printing what `time` is. It will be a integer for sure. So, i think you might need to just do this

```
return render_template('data.html', time=json.loads(r))
```